# XMLHTTPRequest addEventListener

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

I'm using a JQuery Ajax call to send mails.
The php side of this call send mail, one at a time, in a loop.
When the loop is finished it returns some data (message, some html..) to the js script.

It works fine.

To improve the comfort of the user while waiting, I plan to use a progress bar. So I modify both the php side and the js side.
On the php side I include a "return" statement of a mail counter, inside the loop.
On the js side I added a 'xhr' parameter to my Ajax call to listen the returned value of the counter.

HERE is my problem : Js Debug return :

```
 xhr ​<exception>: TypeError
​​​​message: "xhr.responseText.addEventListener is not a function"
```

I can't add a listener to the vale returned par the counter,
The same result by changing 'responseText' to 'response'.
Is it about 'responseText' or 'addEventListener' ?

Did someone can help ?

The complete JS code :

```
function DiffuseOffre(envoi, tab, paquet, dest) {
    //$('#cover-spin').show(0);
    var server = '/Admin/Offres/DiffuseOffre.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: server,
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            envoi: envoi,
            tab: tab,
            paquet: paquet,
            dest: dest
        },
        xhr: function() {
            $("#xhr-rep").show(0);
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.response.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                $("#xhr-rep").text(evt.text);
            })
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            //$('#cover-spin').css("display", "none");
            $('#xhr-rep').css("display", "none");
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('erreur')) {
                $("#dialog-erreur").html(msg.erreur);
                $("#dialog-erreur").dialog("open");
                $("#dialog-erreur").dialog({
                    width: '600px',
                    title: msg.title
                })
            } else {
                $("#dialog-message").html(msg.message);
                $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                    width: '600px',
                    title: msg.title
                })
                if (paquet == 1) {
                    $("#envoi_" + dest).remove();
                    $("#diffuser").remove();
                }
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('encours')) {
                    $("#en_cours").html(msg.encours);
                }
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('fieldset')) {
                    $("#" + msg.fieldset).remove();
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It should be `xhr.addEventListener()`. `responseText` is a string.

Comment: @Barmar OK, thanks. The error disapeared. I found in MDN that it was a property. I'm a bit confused with xhr and how it deal with events from a remote file.
BUT.... nowit is not better : my php file is no more fired, and more debug info from js.
Do I open a new thread ?

Comment: The `xhr:` function needs to end with `return xhr`.

Comment: Don't know why but it is Ok, It's fine my php is fired again. Now I have some troubles  to deal with this phpt :-)
I'll see that tomorrow.
Thank you.